# What's the command-way to find type of connectors (slots) for HDD and DVD-ROM?

Tags: ssd, sata

I want to upgrade my laptop by adding a SSD. I have two plans:

- First, putting SSD in place of cd-rom by a caddy if both HDD and cd-rom have same type of connectors.
- Or, if the speed of cd-rom connector is limited in compare to the HDD connector, then I should replace the current HDD by SSD and then I will put the HDD in place of the cd-rom.

So, I need to find type of their connectors!

`ls -l /sys/block/sd?`

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Oct 17 17:29 /sys/block/sda -> ../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.2/ata1/host0/target0:0:0/0:0:0:0/block/sda
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Oct 17 19:23 /sys/block/sdb -> ../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.2/ata2/host1/target1:0:0/1:0:0:0/block/sdb
```

Comment: What does this have to do with Ubuntu?

Comment: Is this a laptop or desktop?

Comment: `sudo lshw -c storage` might useful.

Comment: @pl_rock  How is question about RAM duplicate of one asking about Hard Drive connectors ? Neither question nor answers mentioned anything related to HDDs. This one isn't a duplicate

Comment: @muru What about DVD_ROM? I need to compare them to find is the DVD_ROM slot different to HDD or not!

Comment: @AndroidDev, Laptop; It has been mentioned in th Q.

Comment: Also try: `sudo hdparm -I /dev/sd* | grep -i transport`

Comment: @muru, Question is updated now.

Comment: @mini sorry, I mistyped, the second command should have been `sudo hdparm -I /dev/s?? | grep -i transport`. Anyway, it looks you have both SATA 6 Gbps and 3 Gbps (if I'm interpreting the widths of the ioports correctly) - now the hard part is figuring out which port is which.

Comment: @muru, Thx; Seems they are both same type (: May you send your comment as an answer to be marked as the right answer to this Q?